# Eclipse 2020-06 Java only shows localJavaApplication launchers, and no javaApplet launchers

Tags: java, eclipse

I've updated (clean folder) to Eclipse 2020-06, and noticed that when I run my java program, it only shows my OpenGL launchers. After further investigating, it turns out that it only shows launchers for localJavaApplication. All launchers that use javaApplet don't show up, and simply changing javaApplet to localJavaApplication in the launcher, makes it show up under configurations.

The javaApplet launchers do work fine, so if I select the launcher in the package explorer and run it, it works fine.

But due to it not showing up under configurations, it is also not saved as last used configuration, and I have to always click and run the specific launcher, where as before I could just click and run the project.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Ps. I'm running jre1.8.0_251, in case that matters.

EDIT:

To clarify, if I change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.javaApplet">
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
```

The launcher shows up under available configurations when I try to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

In the Preferences look at 'Run/Debug > Launching > Launch Configurations'

Check that the 'Java Applet' entry in the filter table is **not** checked (or unchecked the 'Filter checked launch configuration types' option).

Comment: 'Filter checked launch configuration types' is not checked, and neither is 'java applet' in the disabled box below it. Thanks for the tip though, but that doesn't seem to be it unfortunately